# DocuSign getRecipientView ttl_expired error

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign API to POST to the **Post Recipient View** URL.

I receive a response URL, but if I follow the URL it tells me: `...?event=ttl_expired`.

*Example URL: https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/startinsession.aspx?t=66e01470-4fcb-xxxx-xxxx-2f9029036d21*

I'm using the URL within seconds, so is there a reason I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

TTL does indeed refer to "Time to Life" so if you're getting that error and you're positive it's within the 5 minute TTL window (2 seconds sounds well inside :]) then I would guess one of three things:

1. You're requesting a signing URL on an invalid envelope (ie you're not the sender or do not have rights on it)
2. You're requesting for a recipient that is not properly embedded.
3. You're requesting on a completed envelope or other terminal state (like voided).

Please confirm it's not one of these 3 things causing your error.

Comment: With regards to **points 1 and 3**: The envelope is valid as I'm able to fetch the status and recipients. The status is "sent", and nothing has been signed yet. **Point 2**: The document was created using the DocuSign console, however the recipients were added using the API. Does that make a difference?

Comment: It might.  Try making the "Get Recipient Status" API call on the envelope so that you can view the recipient data.  That will probably show that the `clientUserId` is missing or wrong or highlight some other issue.