# #docusignapi frequent event=ttl_expired when using inline signing

Tags: docusignapi

When using docusign inline signing api, I get event=ttl_expired frequently. I even tried using the Docusign API Explorer and the same thing happens. For every two out of three URLs that I get, I get the ttl_expired error. I checked the possible reasons given in [DocuSign getRecipientView ttl_expired error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28113846/docusign-getrecipientview-ttl-expired-error) but to no avail.

Is there something that I am missing here?

The truncated sample json is below. I have replaced the mail IDs & name field.

```
 {
      signers: [{
                    name: 'Name',
                    email: 'mail@example.com',
                    text_tabs: [
                        {
                            label: 'Name Field',
                            anchor_string: 'Name:',
                            anchor_x_offset: '100',
                            anchor_y_offset: '-10',
                            document_id: '1',
                            page_number: '10',
                            required: true,
                            width: 200,
                            height: 10
                        }
                    ],
                    sign_here_tabs: [
                        {
                            label: 'Signature',
                            anchor_string: 'Signature',
                            anchor_x_offset: '100',
                            anchor_y_offset: '-20',
                            document_id: '1',
                            page_number: '10',
                        }
                    ],
                    routing_order: 1,
                    embedded: true,
                    role_name: 'FirstRole',
                    clientUserId: 1
                },
                {
                    name: 'Another Name',
                    email: 'Anothermail@example.com',
                    sign_here_tabs: [
                        {
                            anchor_string: 'COMPANY:',
                            anchor_x_offset: '-20',
                            anchor_y_offset: '-20'
                        }
                    ],
                    routing_order: 2,
                    embedded: false,
                    role_name: 'SecondRole'
                }],
      status: 'sent',
      return_url: 'http://www.google.com',
      email_subject: 'Agreement from Document',
      email_body: 'Please sign the Agreement',
      files: [
          {
              path: File.join('/', 'docusign_docs', 'Agreement.pdf'),
              name: 'Agreement.pdf'
          }
      ]
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Per the other article you reference, the URL that is returned must be opened/used within 300 seconds

2) These are one time use URL's only. If you try to re-use the same URL a second+ time, it will automatically re-direct you to the landing page w/ttl_expired event.

Comment: 1. I am using the URL within seconds of its generation. 2. I am generating a new URL for every use. I know that the URLs are one time use only.

Comment: Is it an AJAX web application which is being used to launch the signing ceremony + generate the one time URL's? I've had experience in which different browsers (e.g: Internet Explorer) was causing the invocation to be called twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your design pattern must be to request the signing url from DocuSign immediately before re-directing the human to the signing url. Anything else will not be reliable.

If you need a longer lasting url for the signing ceremony, then use your own url, to your own application. When the user clicks on that url, your application should:

1. Verify the url
2. Obtain a signing url from DocuSign
3. Redirect the user to the signing url

Comment: I am redirecting as soon as I get the URL.

Comment: Hmmm. Check the API logs from your account. Do they all look right?